# User is part of an AD Group that is nested in the SharePoint group how to relate ad user with SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint, csom

We have added a AD group to SharePoint users group. Now when we login with user, we want to check permission for the logged in AD user.

1. I have added Ad group (example) managers in SharePoint.
2. Now I want show some URL links to only the group(managers).
3. When user logged in, how can I check whether user is manager or not? (Using
   CSOM or JSOM)

Comment: Can you specify further? You added an active directory group to (example) "Site Visitors" SharePoint permission level group.  Now you want to check permissions for what, where and when? And how?  programmatically or SharePoint admin setup or what?

Comment: 1) I have added Ad group (example) managers in SharePoint.
2) Now I want show some URL links to only the group(managers).
3) When user logged in, how can I check whether user is manager or not?(Using CSOM or JSOM)

Comment: For that scenario, you shouldn't need to check the group membership yourself; you can use built-in SharePoint functionality called audience targeting to limit who can see individual web parts on a page.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online or on-prem? Your goal is to add the link to SharePoint navigation (top or quick launch), or a custom link elsewhere?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, the [`SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.containscurrentuser(v=office.14).aspx) property that you would use for this in server-side code is not accessible through the JavaScript client object model (at least not in SP2010 and 2013).

## Option 1: Use group membership visibility as a workaround

One potential workaround is to exploit a combination of two properties that you *can* access on groups via the JavaScript client object model: `OnlyAllowMembersViewMemberhip` and `CanCurrentUserViewMembership`.

If the current user can view group membership for a group that is only set to allow group members to do so, we can assume the user is a group member.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var groupId = 5; // the group membership ID for the group you want to check
var group = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(groupId);
clientContext.load(group,"CanCurrentUserViewMembership");
clientContext.load(group,"OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender,args){
        var isMemberOfGroup = group.get_canCurrentUserViewMembership() && group.get_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership();
        if(isMemberOfGroup){
            doSomething();
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){alert("Whoops! "+args.get_message());}
);
```

This approach will only work if you've set the groups to only be visible to members, and it'll always return a false positive if you have elevated access, such as if you're a site collection administrator or the group owner.

### How to Iterate Through All Site Groups

If you want to apply the above logic to check the current user's membership in all groups on the site (instead of specifying a group by its ID), you can use the modified JavaScript code below.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var groups = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups()
clientContext.load(groups,"Include(CanCurrentUserViewMembership,OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership,Title)");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
function(sender,args){
    var groupIterator = groups.getEnumerator();
    var myGroups = [];
    while(groupIterator.moveNext()){
        var current = groupIterator.get_current();
        var isMemberOfGroup = current.get_canCurrentUserViewMembership() && current.get_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership();
        if(isMemberOfGroup){
            myGroups.push(current.get_title()); // this example adds group titles to an array
        }
    }
    alert(myGroups); // show the array
},function(sender,args){"Whoops! "+alert(args.get_message());});
```

## Option 2: Use Audience Targeting as a workaround

For your requirements you may not even need programmatic access to the group membership. You could just set audience targeting on the web parts that you want to be visible only to certain groups; audience targeting should respect AD group membership.

Comment: Thanks Thriggle, I have solved issues with REST api.

Comment: Cool! Would you be able to post your solution as an answer? It might help others.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to load all groups instead of only one? I need to get all groups a user in. My current solution to iterate through all site groups and perform a query to get "CanCurrentUserViewMembership" property but it affects performance.

Comment: @Trike I've expanded my answer with another code example, but you're right, it takes a little longer to load information on all site groups than it does to load a specific one.

Comment: @AjayNikam I am also facing similar issue. could you please share your rest api solution?